# OpenAI package on Python won't use the latest version

Tags: python, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Running the following code in Python only partially produces the expected result, which is that is asks the user for a prompt and then responds. I say 'partially' because it does so using GPT-3, not GPT-4. I do not know why this is so any help would be appreciated.

```
import openai

openai.api_key = 'key'

messages = [{"role": "system", "content":  
              "You are a intelligent assistant."}]

while True: 
    message = input("User : ") 
    if message: 
        messages.append( 
            {"role": "user", "content": message}, 
        ) 
        chat = openai.ChatCompletion.create( 
            model="gpt-4", messages=messages 
        ) 
      
    reply = chat.choices[0].message.content 
    print(f"ChatGPT: {reply}") 
    messages.append({"role": "assistant", "content": reply})
```